# why CSS effect and double values getting printed in view on web2py?

Tags: python, html, css, web2py

I have this below code in view of web2py

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET}}
{{import json}}
<style type="text/css">
.myTable { width:100%;background-color:#eee;border-collapse:collapse; }
.myTable TH { background-color:#8B0000;color:white;width:50%; }
.myTable TD, .myTable TH { padding:5px;border:1px solid #000; text-align:Center }
</style>
<table class="myTable">
    {{=TABLE(THEAD(TR([TH(c) for c in colnames])),
        [TR(row) for row in rows])}}
</table>
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

1. But, I am not sure why I am not able to see CSS being used while displaying output. CSS effect is not seen
2. Also, I am returning colnames and rows in controller as

> return dict(colnames = colnames, rows = rows)

Not sure why I am getting values in colnames and rows list when I call view html in web2py?
It is printing tables and also values in colnames and rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{=TABLE(THEAD(TR([TH(c) for c in colnames])),
         [TR(row) for row in rows])}}
```

The above already produces a table (that's what the `TABLE` helper does), so you are wrapping one table element inside another -- that is, the HTML will look like:

```
<table class="myTable">
    <table><thead><tr><th>...
    </table>
</table>
```

Instead, just add the "myTable" class to the `TABLE` helper:

```
{{=TABLE(THEAD(TR([TH(c) for c in colnames])),
         [TR(row) for row in rows],
         _class='myTable')}}
```